# FlutterFire Dynamic Links never being recieved by app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm implementing email-link signin for my (android but eventually iOS) Flutter app using Firebase.

I eventually managed to send an email successfully to the user with a dynamic link that opens the app when you click it, however, the dynamic link never gets received in-app (.getInitialLink() is always null)

My `main()` function looks like this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  debugPrint('A ${initialLink?.link}');
  if (initialLink != null) {
    final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.path)) {
      debugPrint('A signed in with email link');
    }
  }

  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen(
    (pendingDynamicLinkData) {
      debugPrint('B ${pendingDynamicLinkData.link}');
      final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link;
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.path)) {
        debugPrint('B signed in with email link');
      }
    },
  ).onError((error) {
    debugPrint('ERROR: $error');
  });

  runApp(const App());
}
```

`.getInitialLink()` is ALWAYS null and `.onLink` never emits any data of any kind.

Dependencies:

```
...
- firebase_auth 4.2.10 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_auth_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- firebase_core 2.7.1 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_dynamic_links 5.0.16 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
...
```

`flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on Manjaro Linux 6.1.12-1-MANJARO, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

I've asked in Flutter's dedicated Discord server for seeking help, but due to the nature of that server, all your questions get drowned out and nobody gets answered.

When I tried to search for an answer to this problem on Google I found several GitHub issues on the topic but all of them were regarding iOS and none of them ever reached a definitive answer (they were all closed automatically due to inactivity).

I'm a little tired of debugging these SDKs and it's a real killer to my productivity
If anyone could offer even the tiniest bit of advice it'd be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after quite some time
For some reason, the `firebase_dynamic_links` started working again, but it still didn't make it past the

```dart
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.path)) {
```

check

Turns out `deepLink.path` did not include the path parameters like `oobCode` (thank you ever so much, VSCode debug tool for helping me find this)

I changed it to a simple `deepLink.toString()` and now it works.
Phew